# Getting today's date in google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get Today's date as a variable to be able to compare how it's been since a date registered in the Spreadsheet.

However i have tried the syntax:

```
var now = new Date();
```

But it returns

> 31/12/1899.

How can I fix it?

```
function onEdit(event) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
      var now = new Date();


      if(r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() <= (now -10)) {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).setBackgroundColor('#DBFF33');
        ss.getRange('B3').setValue(now);
      }

      else {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script date objects are similar but slightly different to core JavaScript date objects. The [reference](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates) goes through the details.

In the [Date Math](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#date_math) section they recommend calculating dates using the date.getTime() function and adding or subtracting milliseconds and explicitly creating a new date:

```
var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var checkDate = new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY * 10);
```

Subtracting 10 from a Date object just seems to convert it to an integer and it is no longer recognised as a date.

So in your case to check for a date that is older than 10 days you should do the following:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var now = new Date();

  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var checkDate = new Date(now.getTime() - (MILLIS_PER_DAY * 10));

  if (r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() <= checkDate) {

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).setBackgroundColor('#DBFF33');
    ss.getRange('B3').setValue(now);
  } else {

  }
}
```